# How to enable mixed content in Chrome using OS-X

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mixed-content

I need to unblock mixed content to view an unsecure webpage on secured website. That's what I got recomended by website's tech support:
"What is happening is that tearsheeting is always secure, as you can see your tearsheeted document starts with https and there is no way around this, and the style sheet for your website is an insecure element. Because your browser is set to block mixed content by default, it is preventing the style sheet from loading."

I cant find a way to do that. If I click shield or lock icon it doesn't give me an option to load the content. I'm using OS-X.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can append

```
--allow-running-insecure-content
```

I would recommend creating a shortcut/script to run this:

```
open -a "Google Chrome" --args --allow-running-insecure-content
```

And then renaming the shortcut/script to "Non-secure Chrome" for future reference.

Comment: I just realized you asked for OS-X, not Windows. Edited.